# Hard drive partition table seems to have broken during a clean install of freya 0.3.1

Tags: release-freya, boot, grub

So as the heading states, I did a clean install as an upgrade, rather than upgrading the os from 0.3 to 0.3.1. I basically chose to reformat the drive, because its a work laptop and all my documents are stored on my external.

After installing the the os using my bootable flash, I can not restart back into elementary, and get directed to the grub command line immediately every time i reboot.

I followed [this](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/776643-how-to-rescue-a-non-booting-grub-2-on-linux/) link to try fix any issues with grub, but now i cant even boot through the usb.

Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 0):

[This worked.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1492801) Probably a duplicate, sorry for that.